# jest/enzyme test event listener removed

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

Learning jest and enzyme to test react apps, bootstrapped with create-react-app.

Mocking add/removeEventListener crashes using `unmount` after `shallow` and gives warning using `unmount` after `mount`, see below. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

My test:

```
it('should add and remove resize event handler', () => {
  const adder = jest
    .spyOn(global, 'addEventListener')
    .mockImplementation(() => {});
  const remover = jest
    .spyOn(global, 'removeEventListener')
    .mockImplementation(() => {});
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  // this seems to work
  expect(adder).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // causing issues
  wrapper.unmount();
  expect(remover).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

using `unmount` after `mount`:

```
  console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
    Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

    Please check the code for the App component.
```

using `unmount` after `shallow`:

```
/home/nik/projects/learn/jest/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:20
  throw err;
  ^

Invariant Violation: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Invalid component element.
    at invariant (/home/nik/projects/learn/jest/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
    at ReactShallowRenderer.render (/home/nik/projects/learn/jest/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:104:38)
    at Updater.enqueueSetState (/home/nik/projects/learn/jest/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:329:20)
    at App.Object.<anonymous>.Component.setState (/home/nik/projects/learn/jest/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:237:16)
    at loadData.then.results (/home/nik/projects/learn/jest/src/App.js:15:12)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c react-scripts test --env=jsdom
Directory: /home/nik/projects/learn/jest
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/nik/projects/learn/jest/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Can you post the source code for `App`?

Comment: here it is: https://github.com/nikrb/cra-jest-play/blob/jest-fetch-save/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the unmount in promise

```
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(remover).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

also missed a clue in the error, 'loadData' - wasn't mocking:

```
  jest.spyOn(App.prototype, 'loadData')
    .mockImplementation(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve([topics, subTopics]))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the first problem, you must take steps to avoid calling `setState` after unmount the component.

The easier way to go about this is by maintaining `_isMounted` flag which you will check before calling setState:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._isMounted = true;

  this.loadData().then(results => {
    if (!this._isMounted) {
      return;
    }

    const [topics, subTopics, ...rest] = results;

    this.setState({ topics, subTopics });
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', this.someHandler);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._isMounted = false;

  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.someHandler);
}
```

You can read more about this problem and find another solution in the React Blog: https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: I don't like your solution, sorry ... but it got me thinking why was I calling setState in `...Unmount`. I thought maybe I was calling `unmount` too soon so wrapped it in a return `Promise.resolve().then()` and it seems to work, though I can't believe I didn't already try that.